# SSL подключение к сервису

Tags: ssl, wcf, azure

Необходимо создать SSL-подключение к WCF-приложению (Azure). Есть самоподписанный серитификат, залит на хост с приложением. В файлах .cscfg указан сертификат:

```
    <Certificates>
      <Certificate name="SampleCertificate"
          thumbprint="<отпечаток>"
          thumbprintAlgorithm="sha1" />
    </Certificates>
```

В файле .csdef указано:

```
<Certificates>
  <Certificate name="SampleCertificate"
               storeLocation="LocalMachine"
               storeName="CN"
               permissionLevel="limitedOrElevated" />
</Certificates>    
...
<Bindings>
  <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="Endpoint1" />
  <Binding name="HttpsIn" endpointName="HttpsIn" />
</Bindings>
...
<Endpoints>
  <InputEndpoint name="Endpoint1" protocol="http" port="80" />
  <InputEndpoint name="HttpsIn" protocol="https" port="443"
         certificate="SampleCertificate" />
</Endpoints>
```

web.config:

```
<bindings>
  <wsDualHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WSDualHttpBinding_Config"/>
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Cetrificatte"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsDualHttpBinding>
</bindings>
...
<host>
  <baseAddresses>
    <add baseAddress="https://<хост>"/>
  </baseAddresses>
</host>
```

При отправке на хост ошибка о том, что сертификат, связанный с конечной точкой ввода HTTPS HttpsIn, не содержит закрытый ключ. Как в конфиге указать секретный ключ? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в том, что необходимо создать сертификат, который будет содержать в себе приватный ключ