# Создать сертификат с приватным ключом

Tags: ssl, azure

Создан сомоподписанный crt-сертификат с помощью OpenSSL. Он используется в Azure. Но проблема в том, в сертификате нет приватного ключа. Способа создать сертификат, в котором будет приватный  ключ, не нашел. Прошу помощи

Comment: А зачем вам приватный ключ?

Comment: В сертификате по определению не должно быть никакого приватного ключа

Comment: @Softovick, при отправке WCF-приложения на Azure возникает ошибка о том, что сертификат не содержит приватного ключа

Comment: Собственно, [конкретизация проблемы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1197497/ssl-подключение-к-сервису)

Comment: Просто сделайте этот сертификат самостоятельно. Обычно используют openssl. Насколько я помнял в старой версии формата как раз приватный ключ вместе с сертификатом в одном pem-файле содержится. Возможно это то, что вам нужно. В гугле полно инструкций.

Answer (score 0):

Решение заключается в том, чтобы создать pfx-файл из имеющихся crt и key-файлов

UPD. Нет, лень не было =)

1. Создание ключа и crt-файла:

```
openssl req -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -sha256 -keyout key.key -out test.csr
```

2. Объединение в pfx-файл:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out ssl.pfx -inkey key.key -in test.crt
```

Выполнялось в Windows 10, но в Linux'е не должно быть отличий

Comment: лучше опишите поподробнее, что и как вы решили. понятно, что вам, скорее всего, лень, но если у др. людей возникнет такой же вопрос, как и у вас, то они скорее всего найдут именно ваш вопрос, и увидев ответ, как ваш, они могут не понять как это правильно реализовать/реализация будет с ошибками. ruSO — это база знаний, и ответы — это способ её пополнения.